# can i run anaconda from notepad++? or, is there a way to use run console on jupyter?

Tags: python

windows 10 64 bit 
i have python 3.6 installed on my pc,
so i'v installed conda2 so i could use python 2 too.

i did the command lines and configuration in conda prompt
and set the environments.

all seem to be set up in the prompt.
i were able to pop the jupyter browser, but i could't find a way to use
the run function or the console... how to activate it?

i'm using notebook++ for python 3.6.
if i could use notebook++ for both python 2 and 3 it will also be great.

i'm sorry if my the title not clear. and please forgive me if the questions 
are foolish. i'm a newbie in programming.

thank you for your patience and help!

Comment: Try to use pyenv to manage python versions.